# Issues RDPing into Win 8 desktop @ work

Tags: windows-8, remote-desktop

I am having a weird issue while trying to RDP into my Window 8 work computer from my Mac/Win7 computer at home. If i lock my screen at work and go home and RDP in - it works just fine. The moment i "Disconnect" my RDP connection, I am unable to log back in. If i get back to work and log in (which works just fine) and then again lock my computer and try to log in from my home computer I can get in just fine the very first time. I can log into any other machine at my work (Win 7 or lower) just fine and as many times as I want with no issues. Any ideas?

If this is not the right place to ask this question can anyone suggest the right place?

Comment: Hi there. There are one or two related questions (see the list on the right). Although they related to previous versions of Windows, could you check to see if they apply and then update your question? Cheers.

Comment: @JulianKnight I did look before i posted the question but i could not find anything. I am not sure if you are seeing different questions in the "Related" section on the right.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/134073/remote-desktop-leaves-host-unresponsive?rq=1, and http://superuser.com/questions/81391/remote-desktop-hangs?rq=1 were the two that caught my eye.